# How to enable Drag and Drop on MaterialCalendarView in android

Tags: android, material-design

I am using *MaterialCalendarView* `com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView` in my application. One of the requirement is to drag and drop custom views on the calendar control.

At the time of drop the target date should be fetched and an appropriate action may be taken. I do not find any method in *MaterialCalendarView* that returns the target date as view. references/ examples - please share if available?